# Oracle Data Guard Error

Tags: oracle, dataguard

```
DGMGRL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Welcome to DGMGRL, type "help" for information.
Connected as SYSDBA.
DGMGRL> show configuration

Configuration - oradb

  Protection Mode: MaxPerformance
  Members:
  oradb    - Primary database
    Error: ORA-16778: redo transport error for one or more databases

    oradb_s2 - Physical standby database
      Warning: ORA-16857: standby disconnected from redo source for longer than specified threshold

Fast-Start Failover: DISABLED

Configuration Status:
ERROR   (status updated 1 second ago)

DGMGRL>
```

is someone has any idea about the following error and warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ORA-12700 to ORA-19400](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/ORA-12700.htm)

> **ORA-16857: standby disconnected from redo source for longer than specified threshold**
>
> **Cause:** The amount of time the standby was disconnected from the redo source database exceeded the value specified by the
>   'TransportDisconnectedThreshold' database property. It is caused by no
>   network connectivity between the redo source and the standby
>   databases.
>
> **Action:** Ensure that there is network connectivity between the redo source and standby databases, and the redo source is working properly.

Comment: Hi Balazs, thanks for the reply actually my standby m/c connection is breaking to physical m/c again and again(after few seconds of connection) and if I do (tnsping standby) from the physical then oracle throwing this error ORA-12541. don't know what's happening all my tns, listener configuration is correct. both m/cs was working fine until tomorrow.

Comment: @steve ORA-12541: TNS: no listener. Your listener is not running. Or your TNS entry is not correct.